# How to extract data from a multipart/form-data response?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am uploading images to a storageAPI using POST method with content-type of multipart/form-data. The api returns an object response that looks as below:

```
{
"id": "6d50c066-cf65-4748-8b9a-183c3526f49b",
"name": "hotel_6.jpg",
"fileKey": "lv/im/5d9feb8e-2ea8-439d-a550-1e937081e085-hotel_6.jpg",
"fileExtension": ".jpg",
"mimeType": "image/jpeg",
"catalogueUrl": {
    "mainUrl": "https://xy.abc.com/lv/im/5d9feb8e-2ea8-439d-a550-1e937081e085-hotel_6.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrls": []
},
"createdAt": "2021-11-25T06:40:40.0869466+00:00"
```

}

How can I extract the variable "mainUrl" from the response so that I can assign its value to the _pictureController? Here is what I have done:

```js
uploadFile() async {
  var accessToken = await sharedPref.read(key);
  var postUrl = '$baseUrl/catalogue?thumbnail=${param.thumbnailTrueFalse}';
  Map < String, String > headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer $accessToken",
  };

  // multipart request object
  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(postUrl));
  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  // add selected file with request
  request.files.add(http.MultipartFile("file", imageStream, imageSize,
    filename: imageName));

  // Send request
  var response = await request.send();

  // Read response
  var result = await response.stream.bytesToString();
  print('readResponse: $result');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = StorageResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(result));
    print('data: $data');
    setState(() {
      _pictureController.text = data.catalogueUrl!.mainUrl!;
    });
    return data;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to upload photo.');
  }
}
```

The "StorageResponse" Class is as follows:

```js
@JsonSerializable()
class StorageResponse {
  var id;
  var name;
  var fileKey;
  var fileExtension;
  var mimeType;
  Catalogue ? catalogueUrl;
  var createdAt;

  StorageResponse({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.fileKey,
    this.fileExtension,
    this.mimeType,
    this.catalogueUrl,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  factory StorageResponse.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) =>
    _$StorageResponseFromJson(json);
  Map < String, dynamic > toJson() => _$StorageResponseToJson(this);

  @override
  toString() {
    String output =
      '{id:${this.id},name:${this.name},fileKey: ${this.fileKey},fileExtension:${this.fileExtension},mimeType: ${this.mimeType}mimeType},catalogueUrl: ${this.catalogueUrl},,createdAt: ${this.createdAt}}';
    return output;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following structure to convert a Json file to a class, and vice versa.

The following structure works properly.

```html
import 'dart:convert';

class StorageResponse {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String fileKey;
  final String fileExtension;
  final String mimeType;
  Catalogue catalogueUrl;
  final DateTime createdAt;

  StorageResponse(
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.fileKey,
    this.fileExtension,
    this.mimeType,
    this.catalogueUrl,
    this.createdAt,
  );

  factory StorageResponse.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return StorageResponse(
        json['id'],
        json['name'],
        json['fileKey'],
        json['fileExtension'],
        json['mimeType'],
        Catalogue.fromMap(json['Catalogue']),
        DateTime.parse(json['createdAt']));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'fileKey': fileKey,
        'fileExtension': fileExtension,
        'mimeType': mimeType,
        'Catalogue': catalogueUrl.toJson(),
        'createdAt': createdAt
      };

  @override
  toString() {
    String output =
        '{id:${this.id},name:${this.name},fileKey: ${this.fileKey},fileExtension:${this.fileExtension},mimeType: ${this.mimeType}mimeType},catalogueUrl: ${this.catalogueUrl},,createdAt: ${this.createdAt}}';
    return output;
  }
}

class Catalogue {
  final String mainUrl;
  final List<String> thumbnailUrls;

  Catalogue(this.mainUrl, this.thumbnailUrls);

  factory Catalogue.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Catalogue(json['mainUrl'], jsonDecode(json['thumbnailUrls']));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'mainUrl': mainUrl, 'thumbnailUrls': jsonEncode(thumbnailUrls)};
}
```

for use

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     var data = StorageResponse.fromMap(jsonDecode(result));
    print('data: $data');
    setState(() {
      _pictureController.text = data.catalogueUrl!.mainUrl!;
    });
    return data;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to upload photo.');
}
```